# Java - Sorting an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting

I am working on a program where I have to count the frequency of food items in a file in order to  sort them in descending order.

For example: if my file has  ( pizza, ice_cream, pasta, pizza )

I want my program to print something similar to this:

1 ice_cream
1 pasta
2 pizza

I am using a bubble sort algorithm but it seems that I am missing something for this algorithm to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Within  class Listabc, I have two local variables and a  method called "compareTo."

```
class Listabc {

     int count = 1;
     String item;


     int compareTo(Listabc listabc) {
        return 0;
     }

}
```

Within my main method, I have  a bubble sort algorithm  to sort the food items in  a descending order

```
public class MainMethod {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

       Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt")));

       List<Listabc> lists = new ArrayList<Listabc>();

       for (int a = 0; a < lists.size() - 1; ++a) {
           for (int b = a + 1; b < lists.size(); b++) {
               if ((lists.get(b)).compareTo(lists.get(a)) > 0) {
                   Listabc temp = lists.get(a);
                   lists.set(a, lists.get(b));
                   lists.set(b, temp);
               }
           }
           System.out.println(lists.get(a));
       }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Start by indenting your code. Then provide more details than "I am missing something for this algorithm to work". You should analyze the results: give sample inputs, expected outputs and actual outputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation of `compareTo` method is **broken**. You need to change it by applying a real comparison:

```
int compareTo(Listabc listabc) {
    return 0; //this means every element is "similar" to another
}
```

Here's an example about comparing the elements by the `item` field:

```
int compareTo(Listabc listabc) {
    return this.item.compareTo(listabc.item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make Listabc implement [comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) you can just call `Collections.sort(lists)`

Answer (score 0):

Below program will sort the list using Collections.sort

```
    public class SortMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> t = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("foodlist.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String item = sc.next();
            if (t.get(item) != null) {
                Integer count = t.get(item);
                t.put(item,++count);
            } else {
                t.put(item, 1);
            }

        }
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>  mp = t.entrySet();
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> ll = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>(mp);
        Collections.sort(ll, new SortMap.ValueComparator());

        System.out.println(ll);


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sc.close();
    }

}

static class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> {

    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }


}

   }
```